# Tcplistener randomly resetting the connection

Tags: .net, f#, network-programming, tcplistener

I'm playing around with a simple webserver written in F#. As I have noticed, if I hit refresh in Firefox, after some tries, I get an error page saying:

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Why does this occur seemingly randomly (increasing the backlog to 1000 didn't help)? Also, why is Firefox the only browser which displays the response of my webserver? I guess my response is not valid, is that right?

The code of the webserver:

```
module Program

open System
open System.Net.Sockets
open System.IO

type TcpListener with
   member this.AsyncAcceptSocket =
    Async.FromBeginEnd(this.BeginAcceptSocket, this.EndAcceptSocket)

type Main =
    static member Init () =
        let tcpListener = new TcpListener(80)        
        tcpListener.Start()

        let rec loop =
            async{                                
                let! socket = tcpListener.AsyncAcceptSocket
                Async.Start(loop)
                let stream = new NetworkStream(socket)
                let streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream)                
                
                streamWriter.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2011 23:59:59 GMT");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/html");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Content-Length: 13540");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("")
                streamWriter.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("<html>");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("<body>");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("<h1>This is the title</h1>");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("</body>");
                streamWriter.Write("</html>");                
                streamWriter.Flush()                        
                stream.Close()
                socket.Close()
            }

        Async.Start(loop)

        Console.ReadLine()

Main.Init()
```

**EDIT**

It seems the problem isn't related to the way I invoked `loop` in the previous solution. I have reduced the program to this (and my problems still persist):

```
module Program

open System
open System.Net.Sockets
open System.IO

let tcpListener = new TcpListener(80)        
tcpListener.Start()

while true do                            
    let socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()
    let stream = new NetworkStream(socket)
    let streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream)                
                
    streamWriter.WriteLine("response");             
    streamWriter.Flush()                        
    stream.Close()
    socket.Close()

Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: That call to `Async.Start(loop)` sure looks wrong..

Comment: Is it possible that it's because your content length is incorrect?

Comment: The call to `Async.Start` _looks_ wrong, but I actually think there is nothing technically wrong with it (it just looks a bit confusing).

Comment: @Tomas : I meant the first one, not the second. Calling `Async.Start` 2 lines into `loop` surely can't work as desired -- wouldn't that attempt to spawn an infinite number of sockets? Or maybe I'm missing some detail regarding `TcpListener`'s behavior...

Comment: @ildjarn I think it is fine, because it will spawn the workflow after a socket was accepted (meaning that a client is connected). The rest of the workflow then processes the current client and the spawned workflow is ready to accept new clients...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working version.  I'd use TcpClient instead of socket so you don't have to manage its underlining stream.

```
module Program

open System
open System.Net
open System.Net.Sockets
open System.IO

type TcpListener with
   member this.AsyncAcceptTcpClient() =
    Async.FromBeginEnd(this.BeginAcceptTcpClient, this.EndAcceptTcpClient)

type Main =
    static member Init() =
        let tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 80)
        tcpListener.Start()

        let writeContent() =
            let stream = new MemoryStream()
            let streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream)
            streamWriter.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">")
            streamWriter.WriteLine("<html>")
            streamWriter.WriteLine("<body>")
            streamWriter.WriteLine("<h1>This is the title</h1>")
            streamWriter.WriteLine("</body>")
            streamWriter.Write("</html>")
            streamWriter.Flush()
            stream

        let rec loop() =
            async {
                use! tcp = tcpListener.AsyncAcceptTcpClient()
                let stream = tcp.GetStream()
                use streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream)
                use content = writeContent()

                streamWriter.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK")
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2011 23:59:59 GMT")
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/html")
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Content-Length: {0}", content.Length)
                streamWriter.WriteLine("")
                streamWriter.Flush()

                content.WriteTo stream
                stream.Flush()
                return! loop()
            }

        Async.Start(loop())

        Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

Main.Init()
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want

```
type TcpListener with
   member this.AsyncAcceptSocket() =
    Async.FromBeginEnd(this.BeginAcceptSocket, this.EndAcceptSocket)

type Main =
    static member Init () =
        let tcpListener = new TcpListener(80)        
        tcpListener.Start()

        let rec loop() =
            async{                                
                let! socket = tcpListener.AsyncAcceptSocket()
                let stream = new NetworkStream(socket)
                let streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream)                

                streamWriter.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Date: Fri, 15 Nov 2011 23:59:59 GMT");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/html");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("Content-Length: 13540");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("")
                streamWriter.WriteLine("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("<html>");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("<body>");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("<h1>This is the title</h1>");
                streamWriter.WriteLine("</body>");
                streamWriter.Write("</html>");                
                streamWriter.Flush()                        
                stream.Close()
                socket.Close()
                return! loop()
            }

        Async.Start(loop())

        Console.ReadLine()

Main.Init()
```

A couple of changes:

1. `loop` is a function, so it needs to accept unit, `()`, both in the definition and when calling it (same with `AsyncAcceptSocket`)
2. your async loop needs to end with `return! loop()`
3. you don't need to call `Async.Start` after `AsyncAcceptSocket` returns

Comment: While these changes are good it still won't work without setting the correct content length.

Comment: I've never generated an HTML response manually; those were just things that stood out to me.

Comment: I don't think any of these changes are a problem. 1) you can start async workflows multiple times provided that they don't capture any state 3) by calling `Async.Start` after accepting a socket, you start listening for a new socket immediately, so you get parallel processing 2) since he started waiting for the next socket (by using `Async.Start` earlier), the `loop` function doesn't need to loop at the end. 

Nevertheless, I agree that the style that the OP used is a bit confusing.

Comment: Right. I couldn't spot a definite problem with his code, but I think this better expresses his intent. Thus my intro: _I think this is what you want_.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really answer to your question, but just a comment regarding the loop and `Async.Start` (I think gradbot's version should probably work, answering your main question).

Anyway, contrary to Daniel and gradbot, I think that your use of `Async.Start` wasn't *wrong*, but maybe just confusing (and confusingly named).

- The way you implemented it is that you wait for a socket, then start a new async (ready to accept new socket immediately) and then you process the rest of the work. This means, you can process requests in parallel.
- The way gradbot and Daniel implemented it is that they accept a socket, send reply to the caller and then wait for another socket. This means that the processing is sequential!

I think the confusion comes from the way you wrote it - I would probably start the processing of the current socket as a new asynchronous workflow and then wait for a next socket (I believe this is easier to understand, but I think your  version was correct too):

```
// Asynchronous function that handles communication with a single client
let handleClient (tcp:TcpClient) = 
  async { 
    try
      let stream = tcp.GetStream() 
      use streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream) 
      use content = writeContent() 

      streamWriter.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK") 
      // Some stuff omitted
      streamWriter.Flush() 

      content.WriteTo stream 
      stream.Flush() 
    finally
      tcp.Dispose() 
  } 

let mainLoop = 
  async {     
    while true do
      // Wait for a client and start async workflow to process it
      let! tcp = tcpListener.AsyncAcceptTcpClient() 
      Async.Start(handleClient tcp) }
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, my original intention was to process requests in parallel, but your solution is much more clear than mine.